# When I generate MSP for some organization, I can confirm Admin and User. What does this mean?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

When I generate MSP for some organization, I can confirm Admin and User. What does this mean?
Does this mean client node?

And additionally,

1. can some clients join an organization?
2. Is one channel matched with one consortium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin and user are roles (principals), so you will be able to define fine grained policy controls, meaning that you could separate certain concerns by allowing them to be controlled by admins only and restricted for regular users (or members). For example you could have chaincode instantiation policy such that only organization admins will be able to instantiate the chaincode.

> can some clients join an organization?

By providing client valid certificate signed with organization CA, you can claim that client has join the organization, moreover you can enroll client within Fabric-CA, which basically will end up with Fabric-CA providing client signed certificate.

> Is one channel matched with one consortium?

Not exactly, you can have as many channel as you want to within single consortium, for example you can divide your consortium into subgroups each of them could have channel of their own. You cannot have multiple consortiums within one channel.

Comment: Does the role mean a role of a client?

Comment: Yes, exactly, this is the role of the user which is essentially a client

Comment: um, I'm confused for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105859/if-peers-use-the-same-chain-code-is-there-any-chance-that-endorsement-of-endors. because it explained the role exists for a peer(You said this is for a client).

Comment: I think client is a user for application and peer is a user for chaincodes or a ledger.