# If peers use the same chain code, is there any chance that Endorsement of Endorsement Policy will be different?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I will ask you thought Endorsement Policy example below

```
peer chaincode instantiate -C <channelid> -n mycc -P "AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"
```

**My understanding(Promise)**

- Org1.member or Org2.member refer to Peer.
- The example means that Org1.member and Org2.member should have to get the same result as instantiating mycc.

**Question**

1. If Org1.member and Org2.member have same chaincode, could their 
   result be different?
2. Are Org1.member and Org2.member refer to one peer of Organization?
   (2-1. If so, does the peer be set on organization randomly?)
3. Can I use regular expressions like "AND('Org1.member > 10', 'Org2.member > 10')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have referred to the fabric documentation on endorsement already. If not, then please find it here [endorsement-policies](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/endorsement-policies.html)

> A principal is described in terms of the MSP that is tasked to validate the identity of the signer and of the role that the signer has within that MSP. Currently, two roles are supported: member and admin. Principals are described as MSP.ROLE, where MSP is the MSP ID that is required, and ROLE is either one of the two strings member and admin. Examples of valid principals are 'Org0.admin' (any administrator of the Org0 MSP) or 'Org1.member' (any member of the Org1 MSP).

AND (Org1.member, Org2.member) means that for successful endorsement, the transaction proposal response which is sent to Orderer ( from the client SDK) is expected to be signed by the member certificate of  Peer of org1  and member certificate of the Peer of org2

1. It is possible to have different result if your chaincode is Non-Deterministic ( ie, say its getting current time etc and putState() ). So write sets can be different.
2. Org1.member & Org2.member are two different Peers. One peer belonging to Org1 and another peer belonging to Org2. [ You cannot have the Peer belonging to two organizations randomly ]
3. I am not sure. Please check the link of Fabric Documentation above.

Comment: A. If Org1 consist of 3 peers, Org1.member is one of them?

Comment: B. Do Org1.member and Org2.member use the same chaincode?

Comment: Q1. Yes, Org1.member means member role in Org1 organization. So any of the peers of Org1 who has joined your channel should be included.

Comment: Q2. Endorsements are against transactions. So obviously Org1.member and Org2.member should sign the the transaction against the same chaincode.

Comment: Link is dead. 
Does it mean if I started 3 peers for Org1 and I write this : "2-of": [{"signed-by": 0}] will work like "2/3 of peers should agree to accept this tx" ?