# Endorsement - when only 1 org and multiple peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am using composer (running on fabric network) with one org and two peers. I would like to know how endorsement works in this scenario?

I understood from docs and rocket chat, that endorsement policy cannot be defined my case since there is only one org. Therefore, if peers in this org produce different results then how will endorsement works? will there be error?

Chaincode is installed on all the peers in this org. Do they automatically become endorsing peers?

Please explain :)

Answer (score 0):

see the first explanation of a similar endorsement policy (ie peers in the same Org) -> [Endorsement policy doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292170/endorsement-policy-doesnt-work)

On 2nd question - ordinarily if you install chaincode on them they would be - but depends on how you set up your network see http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/peers/peers.html http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/chaincode4noah.html and http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/arch-deep-dive.html